# Absolute line numbers in spacemacs

Tags: emacs24, spacemacs

Does the spacemacs have a absolute line number setting, opposed to relative line numbers in the emacs dot files " dotspacemacs-line-numbers 'relative "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set it to `t`

From the documentation:

> Documentation: Control line numbers activation. If set to ‘t’ or
>   ‘relative’ line numbers are turned on in all ‘prog-mode’ and
>   ‘text-mode’ derivatives. If set to ‘relative’, line numbers are
>   relative.

Comment: Oh ok, I have been trying to set it to 'prog-mode or 'text-mode'.